# Как сгладить углы у элемента EditView в Android?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Требуется сгладить края у элемента ввода текста. Допустим есть такая xml разметка:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
</EditText>
```

Каким образом её нужно поменять что бы её углы были более гладкими?

К сожалению, я не нашел очевидных свойств у элемента EditText

Comment: возможно нарисовать самому и подставить....

Comment: посмотрите в сторону background и кастомного вида

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо делать кастомный `EditText` - то есть писать собственную ее реализацию. Не так сложно как может показаться.

Пример кода кастомного `TextView` с закругленными краями приведен [здесь](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/view/BubbleTextView.java?r=16)

Comment: Спасибо, Вы помогли